# How to figure out the cloud account name for a Microsoft OneDrive on desktop

Tags: onedrive

I have a Microsoft OneDrive on my Windows 7 desktop.  I can copy files to it. How do I determine the web-account-name associated with this folder, so I can log in to the web interface and see these files in the cloud?

Comment: Log out of your account within the OneDrive client, then log into the account, it will display the username or it should.  You can also go to your OneDrive accounts through a browser to determine which account is the correct one

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "the OneDrive client". The OneDrive is simply a folder in the FileExplorer.  How do I find out what email address is associated with it?   The two possible email addresses I've tried do each have a OneDrive cloud account, but the files up there are not the same as the files in the OneDrive folder on the hard drive.

Comment: Your using Windows 7 which means you have the legacy OneDrive sync client installed.

Comment: Pretty soon, "legacy" will mean "last year's version" :)

Comment: nope it won't;  OneDrive is built into Windows 8 and Windows 10, they don't have a desktop client, do some research on OneDrive before making comments like that